# Is there an option for task switching similar to MacOs?

Tags: shortcut-keys

I am frequently working on a Mac at Work, but I still prefer Ubuntu on my personal computer. But there is one feature of the Mac Os that I would like to use on Ubuntu as well. On Mac you can see all windows of a specific program running with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Down</kbd> and all windows with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Up</kbd>. Is there something similar for Ubuntu available? The task switching with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> is tedious and not very efficient (grouping of tabs of same program is annoying and if you turn that off, you have to many tabs to go through).

Answer (score 0):

Mostly:  Alt+`
(Alt + plus key left of the "1", above the "Tab")

https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-keyboard-shortcuts.html